# How to detect mouse move (or enter) in GTK application?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to detect mouse entering the main window, I tried using `motion-notify-event`:
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Widget.motion-notify-event.html

But in the `event.type` instead of giving me the actual `GDK_MOTION_NOTIFY` event, I keep getting `GDK_DELETE` for some reason... I tried searching for code sample or SO for similar question but didn't find anything yet.

I've read through this question: [How does GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147662/how-does-gdk-pointer-motion-hint-mask-work)

But it looks like I must bind a GtkDrawArea in order to detect mouse movement, which is not what I want, I just want general mouse move event whenever the mouse is enter/leave my application. Is there a way to do that?

This is the simple callback I'm using to test mouse move detection:

```
GTK_CALLBACK void on_mouse_move(
    GtkWidget* self,
    GdkEventMotion event,
    gpointer user_data
) {
    if (event.type != GDK_DELETE) {
        // .. the event type is always GDK_DELETE
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to set it up to enable the motion event:

```
GtkWidget *mainwin = gui_widget(GUI_MAIN_WIN);
gtk_widget_add_events(mainwin, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK); 
g_signal_connect(mainwin, "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK(on_mouse_move), NULL);
```

But doesn't matter what I do, I always only ever get `GDK_DELETE`:
[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproducible example we can try at home.

Answer (score 0):

To handle mouse enter on your application, you can bind `EventControllerMotion` on your root widget.

Here's my code using `GtkBox` as root widget with `gtk4-rs` rust language binding

```rust
fn build_ui(window: &gtk::ApplicationWindow) {
    let vbox = GtkBox::builder()
        .orientation(Orientation::Vertical)
        .spacing(5)
        .build();

    let btn1 = Button::with_label("Button 1");
    vbox.append(&btn1);
    let btn_temp = Box::new(Button::with_label("Button 3"));
    let button3: &'static Button = Box::leak(btn_temp);
    button3.set_visible(false);

    gl_canvas::gl_area(&vbox);

    let motion_controller = EventControllerMotion::new();

    motion_controller.connect_enter(move |_controller, x, y| {
        println!("enter {} {}", x, y);
        button3.set_visible(true);
    });

    motion_controller.connect_leave(move |_controller| {
        println!("leave");
        button3.set_visible(false);
    });

    vbox.append(button3);

    vbox.add_controller(motion_controller);

    window.set_child(Some(&vbox));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I could use this snippet later if I switch to GTK4, I am currently stuck at GTK3 still.